# Changing Date filter format on Kendo UI Angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I have been facing trouble changing the format of date filter using Kendo UI for Angular 2. My date column is in dd/MM/yyyy format but the date filter format is MM/dd/yyyy when I use `filter="date"` on `kendo grid column`. How can I change this default format of filter to dd/MM/yyyy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in filter templates for the most common data types that are susceptible to further configuration:

[DOCS](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/filtering/built-in-template/#toc-configuring-built-in-filters)
[Built-in date filtering component](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/DateFilterCellComponent/#toc-format)

```
<kendo-grid-column field="FirstOrderedOn" 
  title="First Ordered On" 
  width="240" 
  format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
  <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
     <kendo-grid-date-filter-cell 
      [column]="column" 
      [filter]="filter">
     </kendo-grid-date-filter-cell>
   </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/xG9ZdK9IqFtmlZRHF7F7?p=preview)

Comment: For this filter to work I have to change the string date in json to Date(yyyy,mm,dd) object in javascript as shown in the example.